# Find Keyword in array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, search, multidimensional-array

I have one keyword like this format

`sample text`

Also i have one array like this following format

```
Array
(
   [0] => Canon sample printing text
   [1] => Captain text
   [2] => Canon EOS Kiss X4 (550D / Rebel T2i) + Double Zoom Lens Kit
   [3] => Fresh sample Roasted Seaweed
   [4] => Fresh sample text Seaweed
)
```

I want to find `sample text` keyword in this array. 
My expected result

```
Array
    (
       [0] => Canon sample printing text        //Sample and Text is here
       [1] => Captain text             //Text is here
       [3] => Fresh sample Roasted Seaweed       //Sample is here
       [4] => Fresh sample text Seaweed          //Sample text is here
    )
```

I am already trying `strpos` but its not getting correct answer

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `preg_grep` will do the job:

```
$arr = array(
    'Canon sample printing text',
    'Captain text',
    'Canon EOS Kiss X4 (550D / Rebel T2i) + Double Zoom Lens Kit',
    'Fresh sample Roasted Seaweed',
    'Fresh sample text Seaweed'
);
$matched = preg_grep('~(sample|text)~i', $arr);
print_r($matched);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Canon sample printing text
    [1] => Captain text
    [3] => Fresh sample Roasted Seaweed
    [4] => Fresh sample text Seaweed
)
```

Comment: what does ~i means in preg_grep()?

Comment: `i` is for ignore case and `~` is regex delimiter here.

Answer (score 2):

[preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) does the trick:

```
$input = preg_quote('bl', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$data = array('orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'brown', 'black');

$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $data);
```

hope this will sure work for you.